# Maven plugin installation on Eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I would like to start using Maven on Eclipse Ganymede 3.4 but i'm encountering problems.
When i try to add a site in the software updates pop up under "available software> add"
I get:

```
 No repository found at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/
```

Error reading update site http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/.
  Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update /site.xml

Also, the tutorial shown on the http://eclipse.org/m2e/ page is outdated, the links shown in the video are no longer existing, i think they have been replaced, and it suggest a Jetty implementation, while i would like to keep on using Tomcat.

I have been trying different links found googleing, all extension of the http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/   but with no luck, did anyone of you had the same issue? have some suggestion?

I have tried on Eclipse Helios too but same problem persists,

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because m2eclipse has been moved from the Sonatype repository to its new home under the Eclipse project [as suggested on its Sonatype site](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/).

Try this update site instead as suggested on the plugin's new site:
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.

Comment: thx indeed it loads now, but: requires 'bundle org.hamcrest 0.0.0' but it could not be found, i think you had the same problem while updating the interim branch in Epsilon right?

Comment: and even so you are fighting a loosing battle as 3.4 is very old.  You are best upgrading to Indigo 3.7 ASAP and org.eclipse.m2e it is by far the best M2E release ever I doubt it is compatible with E3.4.